# Using a Hazelcast Client in Unity 5

Tags: java, c#, .net, hazelcast, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to synchronize an application running in the Unity Engine 5 with a jMonkey Java Engine using Hazelcast. Therefore I wanted to use a C# Client, which Hazelcast provides and integrate it into Unity. But it is built in .NET 4.0, which Unity doesn't support. The jMonkey/Java side is not the great deal, but i somehow need to connect my Unity Application with the Hazelcast Cluster. Does anyone know a solution for that? Or is it possible to use the Hazelcast.DLL in Unity although the limitations of Unitys .NET Version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the Hazelcast C# client is buildable on Mono (which is required for Unity) but you can get the sourcecode and try. If you have to do smaller changes to make it compile, we're always happy to see pull requests dropping in on github :)

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-csharp-client

Comment: I have already tried this, but there are too many changes and I haven't really worked with C# or .NET before. Do you have an older .NET 3.5 version of the client? Unitys Mono only supports a maximum version of 3.5.

Comment: There might be code lying around somewhere, however this will be outdated and does not work with current Hazelcast versions anymore. Anyhow do you connect to Hazelcast from a game client? It is not considered good practice to expose Hazelcast nodes to the internet.

Comment: I just try to connect two instances (the Unity- and jMonkey-Application) locally on my PC via Hazelcast. I want to synchronize what happens at the Unity app with the state on the jMonkey app. It is relatively simple data.

Comment: Ok I got response from our client team. We have an old code repository which is private and it would support .NET 3.5, however this - as expected - doesn't support latest Hazelcast versions. The client team mentioned that it might be a reasonable load of work to make it .NET 3.5 compatible but that this would have to be a community effort, due to other duties implied. Apart from that Hazelcast C# is always client only. No node implementation is available.